# Create accordion table in PHP with unsorted array by unix timestamp

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array in PHP that looks something like this:

```
$arras = array(
  '0'=>array('dt_transaction'=>232352),
  '1'=>array('dt_transaction'=>1234),
  '2'=>array('dt_transaction'=>1235),
  '3'=>array('dt_transaction'=>123456),
  '4'=>array('dt_transaction'=>1));
```

(`dt_transaction` is a UNIX timestamp)

But a lot bigger. I have to create a HTML table with this data, but the table must be an accordion jQuery table that groups the data by month.
The array is completely unsorted, I tried to use `usort()` but the array is too big and slow.

Heres the method i tried:

```
usort($arras, function ($a, $b) { return $a['dt_transaction'] - $b['dt_transaction']; });
```

So, i tried to make it in frontend with jQuery append but it's also way too slow. Is there something that allows me to just do a `foreach` and add the rows then automatically sort by date and group by month? Or something simpler.

Comment: Where does the array come from? Can it be sorted at the source?

Comment: It came from a web service and unfortunately it cant't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `array_multisort()`. Example 3 in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) gives you the pattern you're looking for. Not super efficient as you need to loop over the array, but it should do the trick.

```
<?php
$arras = array(
    '0'=>array('dt_transaction'=>232352),
    '1'=>array('dt_transaction'=>1234),
    '2'=>array('dt_transaction'=>1235),
    '3'=>array('dt_transaction'=>123456),
    '4'=>array('dt_transaction'=>1)
);
foreach ($arras as $k=>$v) {
    $trans[$k] = $v["dt_transaction"];
}

array_multisort($trans, SORT_ASC, $arras);

print_r($arras);
```

Comment: This actually works very well, still i have to force the user to reduce the size of their query to prevent my page stops working. Thanks a lot for the help!